# Foreground service type for timer

Tags: android, timer, notifications, foreground-service

My exercise app uses a foreground service to keep an accurate timer going when a user turns off the screen whilst exercising.  There's both a countdown and indefinite count-up timer option.  This works great on devices up until Android 14.  Android 14 requires me to name a [service type](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required).  Without this I get a `android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException`, but when I look at the various service types I don't see any that fit the use case.  It's not sensors that would fit `health`, it's not and exact timer which would fit `systemExempted` as the count-up is indefinite, and the restrictions around `specialUse` makes me think there's no chance it'll be accepted.

Does anyone know which type I should use.  The code for launching the service is as follows:

```
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(exerciseNameStr + " Timer Running")
                .setSmallIcon(exerciseIcons.getResourceId(iconId, 0))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChronometerCountDown(!countUpwards)
                .setUsesChronometer(true)
                .setTimeoutAfter(counterMsec + 1000)
                .setWhen(time)
                .build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        {
            startForeground(100, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_???);
        }
        else
        {
            startForeground(100, notification);   // <-- this code raises an exception for Android 14
        }
```

Is there another way to implement this type of timer showing the tick on the notification?

Comment: So did you get this resolved yet? I am in the same situation as you.

Comment: @AngelKoh - I ended up using `specialUse` and then had to add a video showing the use case for Google to review for my App to stay listed.  It's all good now.  I'll add an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an answer I opted for `specialUse` as follows:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
...
  <application>
...
    <service
        android:name=".CountService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
        android:exported="false">
        <property
            android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
            android:value="Foreground service needed to [fill in details for use case here]..."/>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest
```

In addition to this I had to add a link in Google play console with a video showing the App in action justifying the use-case.  After an extended review, all is well.

Comment: Please could you share what you post in [fill in details for use case here] and what your video contains? Is it show like you just moving app to background and showing notification with info, or something else?

Comment: I describe in plain language why I need a foreground service of this type, and the video is an Android screen capture video (using Screen Recorder) showing the App using this feature.  It was really very straightforward for me, although I could imagine how this could be trickier for other use cases.

Comment: Thank you! Trying the same. Second day in review status. It's really frustrating. I have several sport timer apps and all of this use foreground service for a years before. And now they do not provided default service type for such kind of apps.